# Implication of The axiom of choice

Tags: elementary-set-theory, axiom-of-choice

Let A be a set whose elements are nonempty sets, and let $$B=\bigcup_{X\in A}X$$ 
Then, corresponding to every function $g:A\rightarrow A$, there exists a function $g^{*}:A\rightarrow B$ such that $g^{*}(C)\in g(C)$ iff The Axiom of Choice.

I have the idea to use this:

Suppose A is a set whose elements are mutually disjoint,
nonempty sets, and let $$B=\bigcup_{X\in A}X$$ 
Clearly $A\subseteqq P(B)$, there is a function $r:P(B)\rightarrow A$ such that $r(C)\in C$ for each $C\in P(A)$;if $C=r(A)$ , it follows immediately that C is the required.

Comment: What is your question? One direction is trivial, the other is almost trivial. But without knowing where is the difficulty, this is impossible to clarify.

Comment: that is the fact is not so obvious to me

Comment: Have you written down the definitions? Do you know about function composition? What have you tried to approach this problem? Which part confuses you, and where? Yes. It is sometimes hard to answer these questions when you're just not sure how to start. This is why you should always start by writing out the definitions and some related ideas, and try to brainstorm around them.

Answer (score 0):

The axiom of choice, in its simplest form, states that if $A$ is a set of non-empty sets, then there is a function $f$ with domain $A$, such that $f(X)\in X$ for all $X\in A$. Easily, the range of such $f$ is a subset of $\bigcup_{X\in A}X$, or $B$ as you denote it.

---

Assuming the axiom of choice, then, fix *a* choice function $f$ from $A$. Now for every $g\colon A\to A$ we simply define $g^*$ to be $f\circ g$.

In the other direction, pick $g$ to be the identity function to fallback to the axiom of choice itself.

Comment: I disagree that this is the *simplest* form of AC. Indeed, it still uses the rather complicated concept of a function. The following version is much simpler: For every set $A$ of non-empty sets there exists a set whose intersection with any of the elements of $A$ contains exactly one element.

Comment: @celtschk: Oddly enough your formulation is false without adding the condition of disjointness (take {{0},{1},{0,1}} as an example). And when I say simplest, I mean conceptually.

Comment: My point, of course, is that your "simplest" is wrong without complexifying assumptions. Moreover, to understand that a selector defines a choice function requires a mental step. Formulating AC with choice functions is as straightforward as it can possibly be.

Comment: Granted the error. But pairwise disjointness is still simpler than functions. The formulation with a choice function is, of course, the *most intuitive* one. And quite possibly also the most useful one. I don't know your definition of "conceptual simple", but for me that means "using only simple concepts", and also conceptually, functions are more complicated than intersections.

Comment: @celtschk: There is a reason why Zermelo formulated this with a choice function. The idea that we choose an element from each set is a functional idea (we choose a unique one). Yes, writing it down in the language of set theory using a selector is simpler, I am not disputing that. I am also not disputing that from a set theoretic foundation functions "are more complicated". But, when you get down to brass tacks, the concept of a choice is functional, making it conceptually simpler to talk about choice functions. Other foundations may elect something else entirely (e.g. splitting surjections).